# full URL isn't being parsed correctly to a telegram bot

Tags: python, api, telegram

I have written the following to automate the parsing of text to a telegram bot from a .txt file that is continuously being updated.

```
import urllib.parse
import time
import requests


def post_to_telegram(msg):
    print(msg)
    base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot&text="{}"'.format(msg)
    requests.get(base_url)

urr = ""
name = ""
price = ""
ourLines=0
while(True):
    file1 = open('example.txt', 'r')
    Lines = file1.readlines()
    time.sleep(1)
    while(True):
        if(ourLines==len(Lines)):
            break
        else:
            txt = Lines[ourLines].strip()
            tlist = txt.split("&")
            ourLines=ourLines+1
            for subtxt in tlist:
                if "eventurl=" in subtxt:
                    a = subtxt[9:len(subtxt) - 3]
                    url = 'www.bbey43.com/#'+a.replace("%23", "/")
                    #print(url)
                    urr = url
                elif "bet=" in subtxt:
                    name = urllib.parse.unquote(subtxt[4:len(subtxt)])
                    #print(name)
                elif "price\":" in subtxt:
                    a = subtxt.split("price")[1]
                    price = a.split("\"")[2]
                    #print(price)
            post_to_telegram(urr + " "+ name + " " + price)
```

the 'name' & 'price' is successfully posted to the bot, but the 'url' doesn't post correctly. The only thing that gets through is "bbey43.com/#/

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was rather simple in the end. As the "#" was apart of a URL it required special formatting when being parsed.

Simply adding %23 instead of # solved it.